# Too much arguments converting from V2 to V4

Tags: pine-script

Friends,

Why is this line showing `too much arguments` error when converting V2 to V4?

As I could see, there´s no syntax error here:

```
colors = cond1 ? color(color.red): cond2 ? color(color.aqua, 50) : color(color.red, 50)
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to use `color.new()` for `v4`.

```
colors = cond1 ? color.new(color.red) : cond2 ? color.new(color.aqua, 50) : color.new(color.red, 50)
```